# sql server spatial accuracy problems

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I'm having trouble with inaccurate results from STIntersects in SQL Server 2008 R2.  Perhaps someone can shed some light on what I might be doing wrong - I can't believe that this is the limit of accuracy in SQL Server spatial queries?

```
--example 1
DECLARE @pt1 geography;
DECLARE @pt2 geography;
DECLARE @polygon geography;
SET @polygon = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-172.0000000000 54.0000000000,-164.0000000000 54.0000000000,-164.0000000000 56.0000000000,-172.0000000000 56.0000000000,-172.0000000000 54.0000000000))',4326);
SET @pt1 = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-170.0000000000 54.04)',4326);
SET @pt2 = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-170.0000000000 56.04)',4326);
SELECT @polygon.STIntersects(@pt1); --should be 1, but returns 0 (error is .04 * 60 nautical miles per degree - something like 4.4 km) 
SELECT @polygon.STIntersects(@pt2); --should be 0, but returns 1


--example 2
DECLARE @pt1 geography;
DECLARE @pt2 geography;
DECLARE @polygon geography;
SET @polygon = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-171.0000000000 54.0000000000,-170.0000000000 54.0000000000,-170.0000000000 54.5000000000,-171.0000000000 54.5000000000,-171.0000000000 54.0000000000))',4326);
SET @pt1 = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-170.5000000000 54.001)',4326);
SET @pt2 = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-170.5000000000 54.01)',4326);
SELECT @polygon.STIntersects(@pt1); --should be 1, returns 0
SELECT @polygon.STIntersects(@pt2); --should be 1, returns 1 (less error than in example 1, perhaps due to smaller polygon?)
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012 gives the same results that you've observed on SQL Server 2008 R2, btw.

Comment: I think this is the answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185754/definition-of-geodesic-distance-between-two-points-on-the-same-latitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit as such on the accuracy, it's purely down to the curved earth the Geography type uses.  The rectangle you have drawn in example 1, actually has curved edges, and not straight lines (due the distance over a curved surface).  The horizontal edges in the Northern Hemisphere naturally curve upwards in the middle.

Therefore, @pt1 will always be false, because it sits outside of the polygon's "curved" edges.  As so (buffered so you can see the point).

[image: Poly with PT1]

And likewise, @pt2 actually sits inside the curved edge so will always be true, as so (displayed as buffered and as a hole in the polygon).

[image: Poly with PT2]

Had you rendered these using Geometry (planar model), you would have got the answers you were looking for, but not necessarily the correct one.